# Does a point quadrilateral form a rect in 3D space?

Tags: 3d, rectangles, quadrilateral

I have 4 points with x and y coordinate and would like to find out a way to check if given quadrilateral would be a rectangle in 3D space.

I tried a bunch of conditions, but there was always and edge case where it would reject a real one or it wouldn't be strict enough.

Is there a mathematical formula to achieve this or are there any simple/obvious conditions that I missed?

Example:
First three quadrilaterals on the image below would all be correct. Top one has upper edge pushed away, middle one is orthogonal to the view point and the third is similar to the first one, only that left edge is farther from the view point. 
Last, the red one would be incorrect as no matter how it would be turned in 3D space, it wouldn't be rectangle.

[image: Quads]

Comment: It depends heavily on the kind of perspective used.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I have realized this, and this is why my previous comment is deleted.

Comment: The last one could be a rectangle: the viewer would be looking from the height of the top edge.  The right side of the rectangle is further away from the viewer than the left side.

Comment: But then the top angles wouldn't be ortoghonal, would be? The real quadrilateral comes from a picture taken with a camera and always taken from somewhere above only with angles may vary.

Comment: @ajotatxe: By "kind of perspective" do you actually mean something like "degree of perspective"?

Comment: @JakaKonda: Every convex quadrilateral can map to every other quadrilateral in a perspective projection. A keyword is "homography". What I  believe homography does not give us directly is the ratio between width and height, the aspect ratio. I've just asked a new question trying to understand this part: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398632/relationship-of-aspect-ratio-to-the-homography-matrices-between-a-rectangle-and

Answer (score 0):

Arrange projection of the given four points, say letting $z=0,$ to be clockwise or anticlockwise. Find the four connecting vectors by coordinate differences.

If at each vertex the adjacent side vectors are orthogonal ( so their dot products vanish ), then the four sides belong to a  flat rectangle set in a common plane without being skewed out of plane.